# Java textArea update from multiple textFields

Tags: java, textarea

I want to create a survey in java.
I want to update a TextArea from multiple TextFields and ComboBoxes simultaneously with each one displayed separately on a new line. I only know how to do it for one TextField.
Thanks for your support.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class LoanCalculator2 extends JFrame
{

    private String [] array1={"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    private String [] array2={"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"};
    private String [] array3={"2000", "2001", "2003", "2004", "2005"};
    private String [] array4={"Employed", "Self-Employed", "Unemployed"};

    private JLabel l1=new JLabel("Interest Rate %");//labels
    private JLabel l2=new JLabel("Number Of Years");
    private JLabel l3=new JLabel("Loan Amount");
    private JLabel l4=new JLabel("Interest Accrural Period");
    private JLabel l5=new JLabel("Total Payment");

    private JLabel l6=new JLabel("Date");
    private JLabel l7=new JLabel("Firstname");
    private JLabel l8=new JLabel("Surname");
    private JLabel l9=new JLabel("Age");
    private JLabel l10=new JLabel("Address");
    private JLabel l11=new JLabel("Job Status");

    private JTextField t1=new JTextField();//TextFields
    private JTextField t2=new JTextField();
    private JTextField t3=new JTextField();
    private JTextField t4=new JTextField();
    private JTextField t5=new JTextField();
    private JTextField t6=new JTextField();//firstname
    private JTextField t7=new JTextField();//surname
    private JTextField t8=new JTextField();//age
    private JTextField t9=new JTextField();//address

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);

    private JComboBox cb1=new JComboBox(array1);
    private JComboBox cb2=new JComboBox(array2);
    private JComboBox cb3=new JComboBox(array3);
    private JComboBox cb4=new JComboBox(array4);

    private JPanel p_base=new JPanel();//Panels
    private JPanel p_top=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p_bottom=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p_1=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p_2=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p_3=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p_date=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p_left=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p_right=new JPanel();

    private ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();//Button Group

    boolean state=false;
    private JRadioButton b1=new JRadioButton("Monthly", state);//RadioButtons
    private JRadioButton b2=new JRadioButton("Quarterly", state);
    private JRadioButton b3=new JRadioButton("Half Yearly", state);
    private JRadioButton b4=new JRadioButton("Annually", state);

    private JButton bt1=new JButton("Compute Payment");//Compute Button
    private JButton bt2=new JButton("Reset");//Reset button
    private JButton bt3=new JButton("Verify");//Verify Button

    private TitledBorder p2=new TitledBorder("Compute");//TitleBorder
    private TitledBorder p1=new TitledBorder("Enter Loan amount, Interest rate and Years");
    private TitledBorder p3=new TitledBorder("Interest Accrural Period");
    private TitledBorder p4=new TitledBorder("Loan Data");
    private TitledBorder p5=new TitledBorder("Customer Details");

    GridLayout grid=new GridLayout(4, 1);//ButtonGroup GridLayout

    private Dimension size1=new Dimension(160, 200);
    private Dimension size2=new Dimension(300, 200);

        public LoanCalculator2()//constructor
        {
            frameDimensions();
            setTitle("Loan Application");

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            p_base.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            p_top.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        //  p_bottom.setLayout();

            p_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 5, 5));
            p_1.setBorder(p1);
            p_1.setPreferredSize(size2);

            p_1.add(l1); p_1.add(t1);
            p_1.add(l2); p_1.add(t2);
            p_1.add(l3); p_1.add(t3);
            p_1.add(l4); p_1.add(t4);
            p_1.add(l5); p_1.add(t5);

            t4.setEditable(false);
            t5.setEditable(false);

            p_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
            p_2.setBorder(p2);
            p_2.add(bt2);
            p_2.add(bt1);

            p_3.setLayout(grid);
            p_3.setBorder(p3);
            p_3.setPreferredSize(size1);
            p_3.add(b1);
            p_3.add(b2);
            p_3.add(b3);
            p_3.add(b4);

            group.add(b1);
            group.add(b2);
            group.add(b3);
            group.add(b4);

            p_top.add(p_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p_top.add(p_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            p_top.add(p_3, BorderLayout.WEST);
            p_top.setBorder(p4);

            p_bottom.setBorder(p5);
            p_bottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            p_left.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2,5,5));

            p_date.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            p_date.add(cb1);
            p_date.add(cb2);
            p_date.add(cb3);

            p_left.add(l6); p_left.add(p_date);
            p_left.add(l7); p_left.add(t6);
            p_left.add(l8); p_left.add(t7);
            p_left.add(l9); p_left.add(t8);
            p_left.add(l10); p_left.add(t9);
            p_left.add(l11); p_left.add(cb4);

            p_right.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p_right.add(bt3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            p_bottom.add(p_left, BorderLayout.WEST);
            p_bottom.add(p_right, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            p_base.add(p_top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            p_base.add(p_bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(p_base);//add base panel to frame


            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textArea.setEditable(false);

            TheListener listener=new TheListener();
            bt1.addActionListener(listener);//compute 
            bt2.addActionListener(listener);//reset
            bt3.addActionListener(listener);//verify


        }//end constructor

    private void Month()
    {
        l4.setText("1 Month Payment");
        double i=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
        double r=i/1200;

        double A=Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());

        double n=Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());

        double N=n*12;

        double v1=Math.pow((1+r),-N);
        double v2=(1-v1);
        double v3=(r*A)/v2;
        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###.##");

         t4.setText(""+df.format(v3));

         double v4=v3*N;
         t5.setText(""+df.format(v4));
    }

    private void Quarter()
    {
        l4.setText("3 Month Payment");
        double i=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
        double r=i/400;

        double A=Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());

        double n=Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());

        double N=n*4;

        double v1=Math.pow((1+r),-N);
        double v2=(1-v1);
        double v3=(r*A)/v2;
        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###.##");

         t4.setText(""+df.format(v3));

         double v4=v3*N;
         t5.setText(""+df.format(v4));
    }

    private void Half()
    {
        l4.setText("6 Month Payment");  
        double i=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
        double r=i/200;

        double A=Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());

        double n=Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());

        double N=n*2;

        double v1=Math.pow((1+r),-N);
        double v2=(1-v1);
        double v3=(r*A)/v2;
        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###.##");

         t4.setText(""+df.format(v3));

         double v4=v3*N;
         t5.setText(""+df.format(v4));
    }

    private void Year()
    {
        l4.setText("12 Month Payment"); 
        double i=Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
        double r=i/100;

        double A=Double.parseDouble(t3.getText());

        double n=Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());

        double N=n;

        double v1=Math.pow((1+r),-N);
        double v2=(1-v1);
        double v3=(r*A)/v2;
        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###.##");

         t4.setText(""+df.format(v3));

         double v4=v3*N;
         t5.setText(""+df.format(v4));
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        t1.setText("");
        t2.setText("");
        t3.setText("");
        t4.setText("");
        t5.setText("");

        l4.setText("Interest Accrural Period");

        group.clearSelection();

        frameDimensions();
    }

    private void frameDimensions()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(480,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class TheListener implements ActionListener //Listener Class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) //Event method
        {
            Object target=event.getSource();
            if(target==bt1)
            {
                if(b1.isSelected())
                {
                    Month();
                }

                else if(b2.isSelected())
                {
                    Quarter();
                }

                else if(b3.isSelected())
                {
                    Half();
                }

                else if(b4.isSelected())
                {
                    Year();
                }
                else 
                {
                    t4.setText("Error");
                    t5.setText("Error");
                }

                if(t1.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    t4.setText("No Data");
                    t5.setText("No Data");
                }

                if(t2.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    t4.setText("No Data");
                    t5.setText("No Data");
                }

                if(t3.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    t4.setText("No Data");
                    t5.setText("No Data");
                }
            }

            if(target==bt2)
            {
                Reset();
            }

            if(target==bt3)
            {
                textArea.setText(t6.getText()+t7.getText());
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: We are not here to write your program for you. Post what you have and we can try to assist you.

Comment: Show us an example how you did with one textfield, it shouldn't be so different.. You can attach a `documentListener` for textfields and a `ItemSelectionListener` for combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JTextArea.append` rather then `JTextArea.setText`.  Don't forget to place a new line (`\n`) at the end of each line

You may also wish to place the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` or as you add more text to the text area, it will grow, taking up more space in your UI, for example...

```
p_right.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Take a look at [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks. I got it working the way i wanted and i managed to finish the gui in time for submission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some kind of buffer to store all data in it. Try StringBuilder for example. After that just append whole buffer to your text area